# Manifest merger failed?

Tags: android

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.

> Manifest merger failed : Attribute meta-data#com.google.android.gms.version@value value=(43) from AndroidManifest.xml:21:13-31
>       is also present at [com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:9.0.2] AndroidManifest.xml:23:13-66 value=(@integer/google_play_services_version).
>       Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:value"' to  element at AndroidManifest.xml:19:9-21:33 to override.

Comment: Added folowing in dependency but still doesn't solve my problem:
configurations.all {
resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { details ->
def requested = details.requested
if (requested.group == 'com.android.support') {
if (!requested.name.startsWith("multidex")) {
details.useVersion '25.3.1'
}
}
}
}

Comment: show your **`Build.Gradle`**

Comment: post your Build.Gradle here

Answer (score 0):

add `tools:replace="android:value"` to element at AndroidManifest.xml

this error caused by same element Present in Two or more files